# how to create a web2py app from command line?

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to create a web2py app from command line with -S ... However, I would like to create an app without the "No app, Create one?" question. Is there someway I can create it in a forceful manner.

I have tried app_create() from gluon.admin but there I face the problem of the Request argument. None value for request doesn't seem to work.

Help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see Massimo Di Pierro answered your question [here](http://www.marshut.com/piwqs/web2py-app-creation-from-command-line.html).

Although it is not what you asked about, I'd like to add this answer to hopefully help those who come here for a related problem. I.E. how to create a new web2py app WITHOUT browser IDE, in windows?

Notice in the web2py book chapter 4 it says, "The tar gzipped scaffolding app that ship with web2py is welcome.w2p". Therefore:

1. copy welcome.w2p to mytempdir
2. rename welcome.w2p welcome.gz
3. using winzip[gui] or other  extract welcome.gz to mytempdir
4. mytempdir will contain a new file named welcome.w2p
5. rename welcome.w2p welcome.tar
6. using winzip[gui] or other  extract welcome.tar to mytempdir/appname
7. copy mytempdir/appname into web2py/applications